# Why filter in Datagridview is very slow from textbox with OleDB in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, filtering

I'm trying to filter in Datagridview is very slow from textbox with OleDB in VB.NET.

typing is also slow and also removing or reducing characters becomes slow in the event textbox. Please guide

me is there any solution or method that makes it fast or the code I am using is wrong.

There are a total of four thousand database records

Below the MS Access database file share link :

[database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FT7hU39QbVNbFm3phfY29-cxW2eeWFjO/view?usp=drive_link)

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Function CreateConnection() As String
        Return ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    End Function

 Private Purchase, Sales As New List(Of Invoice)
 Private PurchaseDetails, SaleDetails As New List(Of Detail)
 Private Card As List(Of StockCards)
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
 End Sub
    Private Sub LoadData()
        Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection())
            Purchase = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Purchase"), List(Of Invoice))
            PurchaseDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM PurchaseDetails"), List(Of Detail))
            Sales = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Sales"), List(Of Invoice))
            SaleDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM SalesDetails"), List(Of Detail))
        End Using
        Dim ps = From p In Purchase
                 From pd In PurchaseDetails
                 Where pd.Invono = p.Invono
                 Select
        Invono = p.Invono,
         Invodate = p.InvoDate,
         p.Transaction,
         pd.CodeProduct,
         pd.Barcode,
         pd.Criteria1,
         pd.Criteria2,
         pd.Criteria3,
         pd.Criteria4,
         [IN] = pd.Qty,
         [OUT] = 0,
         BLC = pd.Qty
                 Order By Invodate, Invono
        Dim ss = From s In Sales
                 From sd In SaleDetails
                 Where sd.Invono = s.Invono
                 Select
             Invono = s.Invono,
             Invodate = s.InvoDate,
             s.Transaction,
             sd.CodeProduct,
             sd.Barcode,
             sd.Criteria1,
             sd.Criteria2,
             sd.Criteria3,
             sd.Criteria4,
             [IN] = 0,
             [OUT] =
             sd.Qty,
             BLC = -sd.Qty
                 Order By Invodate, Invono
        Dim Card_temp = ps.Union(ss).OrderBy(Function(w) w.Invodate).ThenBy(Function(w) w.Invono)

        'Dim Card As New List(Of StockCards)
        Card = New List(Of StockCards)
        Dim RunningBalance As Integer = 0
        For Each ct In Card_temp
            Dim sc As New StockCards
            With sc
                .Invono = ct.Invono
                .InvoDate = ct.Invodate
                .Transaction = ct.Transaction
                .CodeProduct = ct.CodeProduct
                .Barcode = ct.Barcode
                .Criteria1 = ct.Criteria1
                .Criteria2 = ct.Criteria2
                .Criteria3 = ct.Criteria3
                .Criteria4 = ct.Criteria4
                .IN = ct.IN
                .OUT = ct.OUT
                .BLC = RunningBalance + ct.BLC
                RunningBalance = .BLC
            End With
            Card.Add(sc)
        Next
        Datagridview1.DataSource = Card
    End Sub
  Private Sub DoFilter()
        If IsHandleCreated Then
            BeginInvoke(
            New Action(
            Sub()
                Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

                If txtCriteria1.TextLength > 0 Then
                    dict.Add("Criteria1", txtCriteria1.Text)
                End If
                If txtCriteria2.TextLength > 0 Then
                    dict.Add("Criteria2", txtCriteria2.Text)
                End If
                If txtCriteria3.TextLength > 0 Then
                    dict.Add("Criteria3", txtCriteria3.Text)
                End If
                If txtCriteria4.TextLength > 0 Then
                    dict.Add("Criteria3", txtCriteria4.Text)
                End If
                ' Do the same for the other 3 boxes.
                Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection())
                    Purchase = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Purchase"), List(Of Invoice))
                    PurchaseDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM PurchaseDetails"), List(Of Detail))
                    Sales = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Sales"), List(Of Invoice))
                    SaleDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM SalesDetails"), List(Of Detail))
                End Using
                Dim ps = From p In Purchase
                         From pd In PurchaseDetails
                         Where pd.Invono = p.Invono
                         Select
        Invono = p.Invono,
         Invodate = p.InvoDate,
         p.Transaction,
         pd.CodeProduct,
         pd.Barcode,
         pd.Criteria1,
         pd.Criteria2,
         pd.Criteria3,
         pd.Criteria4,
         [IN] = pd.Qty,
         [OUT] = 0,
         BLC = pd.Qty
                         Order By Invodate, Invono
                Dim ss = From s In Sales
                         From sd In SaleDetails
                         Where sd.Invono = s.Invono
                         Select
             Invono = s.Invono,
             Invodate = s.InvoDate,
             s.Transaction,
             sd.CodeProduct,
             sd.Barcode,
             sd.Criteria1,
             sd.Criteria2,
             sd.Criteria3,
             sd.Criteria4,
             [IN] = 0,
             [OUT] =
             sd.Qty,
             BLC = -sd.Qty
                         Order By Invodate, Invono
                Dim Card_temp = ps.Union(ss).OrderBy(Function(w) w.Invodate).ThenBy(Function(w) w.Invono)
                'Dim Card As New List(Of StockCards)
                Card = New List(Of StockCards)
                Dim RunningBalance As Integer = 0
                For Each ct In Card_temp
                    Dim sc As New StockCards
                    With sc
                        .Invono = ct.Invono
                        .InvoDate = ct.Invodate
                        .Transaction = ct.Transaction
                        .CodeProduct = ct.CodeProduct
                        .Barcode = ct.Barcode
                        .Criteria1 = ct.Criteria1
                        .Criteria2 = ct.Criteria2
                        .Criteria3 = ct.Criteria3
                        .Criteria4 = ct.Criteria4
                        .IN = ct.IN
                        .OUT = ct.OUT
                        .BLC = RunningBalance + ct.BLC
                        RunningBalance = .BLC
                    End With
                    Card.Add(sc)
                Next
                Datagridview1.DataSource = If(dict.Any(),
                Card.Where(Function(CardCache) CardCache.IsFilterItem(dict)).ToList(),
                Card)
            End Sub))
            Return
     Else

            ' Handle the error case, or do nothing.
        End If
    End Sub
   Private Sub txtCriteria1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCriteria1.TextChanged
        DoFilter()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtCriteria2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCriteria2.TextChanged
        DoFilter()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtCriteria3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCriteria3.TextChanged
        DoFilter()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtCriteria4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCriteria4.TextChanged
        DoFilter()
    End Sub
Public Class StockCards
    Public Property Invono() As String
    Public Property InvoDate() As Date
    Public Property Transaction() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
    Public Property Criteria1() As String
    Public Property Criteria2() As String
    Public Property Criteria3() As String
    Public Property Criteria4() As String
    Public Property [IN] As Integer
    Public Property [OUT] As Integer
    Public Property BLC As Integer

    ' Replace `.Equals` with `.Contains` if needed...
    Public Function IsFilterItem(dict As IDictionary(Of String, String)) As Boolean
        Return dict.All(
            Function(kv) ContainsProperty(kv.Key) AndAlso
            GetPropertyValue(Of String)(kv.Key).
            Equals(kv.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    End Function
    Private Function GetPropertyValue(Of T)(propName As String) As T
        Return DirectCast(Me.GetType().GetProperty(propName)?.GetValue(Me), T)
    End Function

    Private Function ContainsProperty(propName As String) As Boolean
        Return Me.GetType().GetProperty(propName) IsNot Nothing
    End Function
End Class
Public Class Invoice
    Property Invono() As String
    Property InvoDate() As Date
    Property Transaction() As String
End Class

Public Class Detail
    Public Property Invono() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
    Public Property Criteria1() As String
    Public Property Criteria2() As String
    Public Property Criteria3() As String
    Public Property Criteria4() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class
```

result filter datagridview slowly

[image: result filter datagridview slowly]

Comment: You are querying the database every time the `Text` changes, so you will query four times if you type four characters. Better to start/restart a `Timer` every time the `Text` changes, then query when the `Timer` `Ticks`. You would make the `Interval` long enough that the `Tick` wasn't raised in between characters at normal typing speed but short enough that the user wasn't waiting for it to happen when they finished typing. 300-500 should do it, but you can test to see what works best.

Comment: Note that, if the total amount of data is not too large, you can retrieve all the data first up and then filter locally. If you're not querying the database every time, the filter will be quicker.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your suggestion sorry I responded to you too late. because this is just a sample, so each character length is different in the original data, so I'm not interested if I use a timer

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `you can retrieve all the data first up and then filter locally. If you're not querying the database every time, the filter will be quicker.` if this I agree please guide me

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to detect and understand the problem. You have a database and you have an application that searches in this database each time a text box's value changes. So, your process is:

**Each time[1] a filter changes, we send a query[2] to the database**

and the issue is that this process is slow. So, the way to reduce the impact of the problem is to

[1] Reduce the frequency of querying
[2] Improve the performance of querying

Let's suppose you want to search for "B100". In this case, assuming you do not make typo and you write this by hand, you make four value changes in the textbox. This means that 4 queries are executed, the first is searching for "B", the second is searching for "B1", the third is searching for "B10" and the fourth is searching for "B100", whereas you were only interested in the latest search, all the earlier searches being irrelevant for you. So, it makes sense to have a timer that is set to execute the search after a while.

For example, if you have these rules:

- when a filter is changed, you schedule an event to occur after 0.2 seconds
- if there was a filter change before the previous 0.2 seconds' wait ended, reschedule the wait
- when the wait time elapsed, send a single query to the database

This way your search is executed when the search terms are defined instead of repeatedly executing it upon each change, performing the relevant searches and preventing the irrelevant searches. This is just one approach to reduce frequency, but you can do some alternative solution as well, as long as it's clear that search frequency is slowing down the system.

Now, let's see the possible improvements upon query speed. Looking at:

```
                Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection())
                    Purchase = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Purchase"), List(Of Invoice))
                    PurchaseDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM PurchaseDetails"), List(Of Detail))
                    Sales = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Sales"), List(Of Invoice))
                    SaleDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM SalesDetails"), List(Of Detail))
                End Using
```

You are converting these queries into lists, hence you load every record of every table and you apply your sorts and filters later on. Loading 1+ megabyte into memory is a slow process and then you also filter this. Instead, you will need to create the `Query` and apply your `Where` and `OrderBy` and other stuff upon it before you actually run it. So you will load and order only the records that are relevant to this search.

You might also want to index the fields you are filtering by, so when your database executes your searches, then they will be more optimal while doing so.

So, to summarize:

- reduce the frequency of searches
- make sure the filter and sort is part of the query before it's executed in the database
- create indexes where appropriate

PurchaseDetails and SalesDetails should be searched with the help of their foreign keys which reference the purchase and sale they are part of, respectively. Also, if possible it would be great to only load the fields that you need, so instead of `SELECT *` a whitelist of fields you are interested about are usually more performant, because there are some long fields, like explanation or something of the like and you do not need that in the grid, then you win space and time by not loading that field into memory for all records involved. It's also more secure, because, if you have secret fields you do not want to display in any circumstances, then they are better not being sent to the UI at all.

Comment: Sorry I was late in replying, thank you for your suggestion, I am more interested in your recommendation by improving the query by selecting fields from the database

Comment: @siwa86 To achieve that you can replace `SELECT *` to `SELECT yourcolumn1, yourcolumn2, yourcolumn3` listing the columns you want to select, separating by comma and ommitting any columns you do not want to select. If you run the four queries `SELECT * FROM Purchase;SELECT * FROM PurchaseDetails;SELECT * FROM Sales;SELECT * FROM SalesDetails;` then how long does it take?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry I was late in replying. 
OK, I'll try